# Book on the Three body Problem

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, ds.dynamical-systems, books, textbook-recommendation

Hi all, I am looking for a good book about the famous (infamous perhaps?) three body problem -  both theoretical and numerical hardless and accomplishments.

can you help? Thanks

Comment: Should I suggest you begin with the two body problem?

http://thetwobodyproblem.com

Comment: What about *Jules et Jim*, by Pierre-Henri Roché? (See http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_et_Jim_(roman) for more details.)

Comment: Despite the title, the novel by Cixin Liu (tr. Ken Liu) is also unhelpful.

Comment: Maybe it is too much for your needs (and also ten years have passed), but why not give a chance to Yusuke Higher "Celestial mechanics" volume on that precise topic?

Answer (score 9):

For the **Restricted** three-body problem, I suggest:
Dynamical Systems, the Three-Body Problem and Space Mission Design By Marsden,Koon,Lo and Ross Available free at: www2.esm.vt.edu/~sdross/books

This book is a very nice compilation of results, proofs related to symbolic dynamics in the system, and numerical techniques for designing low energy trajectories. A great resource.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a more popular book, then

Florin Diacu & Philip Holmes: [Celestial Encounters:
The Origins of Chaos and Stability](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5913.html)

is a must.